# SCCM 2012 R2 Cannot Run PowerShell Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment COMObject

Tags: powershell, sccm

Through a PowerShell script, I'm trying to interact with SCCM 2012 R2 Task Sequences. A lot of sites refer to using something similar to the following:

```
$tsenv = new-object -ComObject microsoft.sms.tsenvironment
```

First, if there is a better/different way, I'm totally open to it. But for this way, whenever I run that line, regardless of how I loaded the ConfigurationManager module (e.g. launch PowerShell from SCCM console, load the ConfigurationManager.psd1 from an x86 or x64 PowerShell console), it always returns the error below. I've also tried this on lab SCCM 2012 R2 environments and 2 separate production environments:

> "New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ... failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered"

I'm coming up short searching for answers online, so hoping someone here is able to use that ComObject in PowerShell with SCCM 2012 R2 or if I'm just out of luck.

Comment: I thought Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment was only available during OSD?

Comment: I'm using this for OSD Task Sequences. I was trying to test the script before inserting into a task sequence. Is the com object only available if running during the OSD Task Sequences?

Comment: Not sure if it has to be OSD Task Sequence or if any TS will work. This is from the link you posted: The Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment COM object is only available while the task sequence is running, so you need to test your script inside of a task sequence.  (This can be a case where the “convert task sequence environment to PowerShell variables could come in handy: do you testing with hard-coded variables, remove the values before deploying the script.)

Comment: Sheesh. I didn't even see that. Thanks, lahell!

Answer (score 0):

FYI,
In addition to having an active task sequence, you should also make sure that you are running from x64 process when creating the object when running on 64-bit OS, o/w the creation will fail with the 'Class not registered' error as if there is no TS running.